# Objective-C - Expected a type on + function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using an SDK from a 3rd party when I use the sample app, I get no errors, when I add the SDK to my app, I get this error:

`Expected a type` on this line `+(UIImage *)arrowImage;`

I get a bunch of these errors on method definitions like:

```
+(UIColor *)itemsColor;
+ (UIColor *)mainColor;
+ (UIColor *)itemTextColor;
+ (UIColor *)selectionColor;
```

Why am i getting these errors for only these methods? PLEASE HELP!

Here it the complete .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SIMenuConfiguration : NSObject
//Menu width
+ (float)menuWidth;

//Menu item height
+ (float)itemCellHeight;

//Animation duration of menu appearence
+ (float)animationDuration;

//Menu substrate alpha value
+ (float)backgroundAlpha;

//Menu alpha value
+ (float)menuAlpha;

//Value of bounce
+ (float)bounceOffset;

//Arrow image near title
+(UIImage *)arrowImage;

//Distance between Title and arrow image
+ (float)arrowPadding;

//Items color in menu
+(UIColor *)itemsColor;

//Menu color
+ (UIColor *)mainColor;

//Item selection animation speed
+ (float)selectionSpeed;

//Menu item text color
+ (UIColor *)itemTextColor;

//Selection color
+ (UIColor *)selectionColor;
@end
```

Comment: instead of #Import use @Import

Comment: *Hint:* `UIColor` is defined in the UIKit framework ...

Comment: @JP_Mob: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` works as well (and that is still generated by the Xcode templates if you create a new Objective-C file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` with `@import UIKit`. As noted in the comments, `UIColor` is part of UIKit.